# What is the magnitude and phase of the wave represents in the k-space or Fourier space?

Tags: image-processing, fourier-transform, python, dft, power-spectral-density

#Code from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70768384/right-method-for-finding-2-d-spatial-spectrum-from-cross-spectral-densities

I've an array of seismic sensors (say, N=34). Every sensor collect the seismic data. At first, I've found the cross spectral densities (csd) from the every possible pair of seismic sensor, hence it becomes a matrix of size (34*34).
Then I find the wave number or spatial frequency, K which  is based on K = 2*pi*f/v, where f=temporal frequency=10 Hz and v= velocity/speed of the vector field.
So, `kx = np.linspace(-k, k, n * 5) ; ky = np.linspace(-k, k, n * 5)`

Finally, I've performed 2-dimensional DFT of the CSD of a specific frequency with the following 3 signals and got the following plots respectively.

To implement the equation below, I use the code as follows
[image]

$$signal_1 = A* \sin(k_xX + k_yY - \omega t) \tag{1} $$
$$signal_2= A* \sin(k_xX + k_yY - \omega t) +B* \cos(k_xX + k_yY - wt), \\
 K = \omega/c \tag{2}$$

$$signal_3= cmath.exp(-1j*((float(k_x[k]*dx[m])+ float(k_y[l]*dy[n]))))$$

If we plot the spatial spectrum by using signal_1st, I get the following picture
[image: Fog. 01: only sine function]

while I use 'signal_2nd' the spatial spectrum look like as follows: [image: Fig. 02: Sine+ cosine function]

[[image: [Figure:03. Spatial spectrum of a specific frequency: by using <span class=]$$ signal_3$$]" />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y1DtO.jpg)

Can anyone please interpret why the 'red blobs' or the modes of the wave are different in the three plots?

Comment: I tried to clean you your equations but they are hard to read. Please define all symbols that you are using. Is `kx` a single variable or supposed to mean $k  \cdot x$ ?

Comment: K=2*pi*f/c & kx+ ky=kx.ax+ky.ay where ax and ay are the unit vectors. So, Kx is a single variable.

Comment: The question is also posted here https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/694030/what-is-the-physical-meaning-of-bright-red-blobs-if-red-blobs-represent-a-w/694033?noredirect=1#comment1553042_694033

Comment: Your code for the DFT2D does not match the equation in the question. You only use sin, which is only the imaginary part of the basis function. Use the exponential instead.

Comment: @Ash, Thanks. You are right. My question is if I use only imaginary or real part only as the basis function then why two red blobs are being generated? In contrast, if I use 'sin+cosine' then I get only one Red blob. Why and what is the physical interpretation of it?

Comment: @pluto, Sine and cosine are orthogonal. If you multiply a zero phase sine with a zero phase cosine and sum, you will get zero. If you instead multiply a sinusoid with any phase by the exponential, you get a complex number with the same amplitude as the sinusoid (depending on how you sample) and a phase rotation. To extract the amplitude, you apply the absolute value. For the first signal, you see two plots because of a conjugate symmetry (positive and negative frequencies). Because of your basis function and sample points, the sampling of the second signal probably looks more like a DC offset.

Comment: @Ash, Thanks for your answer. I'm happy that you understand my problem. Could you please explain it mathematically [Amplitude, phase, +ve/-ve frequencies] as well as physically in the answer section so that I can accept the answer?

Comment: @Ash- ok, Why there are bright points along the X-axis and Y-axis in fig. 01? Can you please clarify?